# Use intent to load static html?

Tags: android

How can I use an intent to load a static html string?

The following code causes a run-time error:

```
           public void onClick(View v)
                {
                String html = "<html><pre>this is text</pre></html>";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse( html );
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
```

Comment: You have to load the page in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try out loading your text in `WebView` as below:

> ```
> WebView browser;
> String html = "<html><pre>this is text</pre></html>";  
> browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);    
> browser.loadData(html, "UTF-8");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code reference. I have tried and it works.
Android Intent App to load html webpages. Use of Uri.parse(url)

/activity_main.xml
  create a button

```
<Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/intro"

       android:onClick="load" />
```

then the method is declared in MainActivity.java

```
public void load (View view) {
 String url = "http://www.fullchipdesign.com/verilog.htm";
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(intent);

}
```

Complete usage at this link 
http://www.fullchipdesign.com/tyh/android_app_list_intent_html.htm